# How to navigate back to a specific activity in Android Wear

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, wear-os, android-navigation

**Navigation considerations in Android Wear**

In Android Wear, swipping the screen from left to right makes you return to the previous **activity**. I noticed that, if an activity has fragments and you do that gesture, you return to the previous activity, regardless of how many fragments you have inside the activity.

**The problem**

I would like to be able to perform the following navigation, described in the diagram:

[image: navigation diagram]

- My main activity is A;
- If I swipe in B, I go to A;
- If I swipe in C, I
  go to B;
- If I swipe in D, however, I return to A.

That is how I would like my navigation to be, but I couldn't do it in a satisfactory way.

**Attempts**

- One of the approaches was to finish activity C right before entering D. However, it gets a bit confusing, because right after swipping, activity B briefly appears before activity D (which makes sense, since there is a delay between finishing C and starting D, which makes B appear in the background)
- Another attempt was clearing the activity stack from B and C (using flags in `Intent`. The problem, however, is also that, while swipping D, C appears briefly in the background and only disappears after I finish swipping, showing A. This also may confuse the user, because he will briefly see C before getting to A.
- I also tried using fragments, but I realised that it doesn't matter how many fragments I put inside an activity, swipping it will cause the activity to finish. This would work well to go from D to A, but the problem is that when I'm in C, I have to be able to go back to B. So, inflating a single activity with three fragments (B, C and D) wouldn't work that well because of that detail.
- I also thought about using a viewpager with fragments and adding logic to do what I want, but, in terms of code and implementation, I think it could get ugly really fast, specially if I want to change it in the future.  I would have to show pages programmatically and disable swipe to navigate inside the viewpager, so as to not let the user progress through that (because I want the user to navigate only by pressing "Continue" buttons in each screen). Also, when reaching D, I would have to remove B and C so that, when user swipped, he would go back to A. As I said, the code would get ugly really fast.

**Summary**

Having all that in consideration, what I want is to be able to go from C to B by swipping and, when reaching D, the swipe would return the user to A, without showing B or C by accident in the background. I would like the user to actually feel that he's going from D to A, without finding it weird that B or C appear briefly in the background

Answer (score 0):

Try creating A as new intent and clear back stack, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // call this to finish the current activity
```

Comment: The problem about that is as I described. With your code, let's say I'm in C and I go to D. When I do that, C disappears RIGHT BEFORE D appears. So, since B was the previous activity from C, it appears BRIEFLY before D starts. I would like to avoid that effect. If I could finish C ONLY AFTER D start AND appears on the screen, it would work

Comment: this code should be called  only in D when you want go back to A.

Comment: I'm having problem detecting the fling now. I have tried many ways, but it doesn't detect when I'm swipping. When I fix that, I'll let you know if that works

Comment: `GestureDetector` can detect fling, try using it

Comment: I tried many ways with it, but it's simply not working. It never even calls `onFling`. I've been trying many ways, but none of them works

Comment: I'm wondering, considering that the fling is not working, would there be a way to wait for activity D to be completely visible and, just then, execute those lines of code you wrote?

Comment: try running it in `onResume()`

Comment: if you run this code  in `onResume()` activity D will be already visible, because its called after view is created. See [acivity lifecycle]

Comment: I managed to do it by using noHistory=true for the activities I did not want to have a "memory". In my example, it means B and C ONLY when I reach D. Problem now is that, when I go back to activity A, I would like to have its state reset. At the moment, when I swipe back, it keeps the state. Is there a way to reset it?